# JZMQ error: no thread available

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

I'm trying to write a simple java application that would run on a server and do some simple stuff. But currently my application is failing on a weird error i cannot seem to find any information on `Exception in thread "main" org.zeromq.ZMQException: No thread available(0x9523dfe)`

Both services run on the same server, but only my application is failing. I have found only minimal documentation for the C zmq framework. Nothing for java.

The class where the error occurs:

```
public class TestService extends GenericService {

public TestService(String[] args) {
    init(args);
}

private void init(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    serviceId = args[i++];
    servicePort = Integer.valueOf(args[i++]);
}

private void retrieveConfig() {

}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running");
    initZmq(); // <---- Here
    retrieveConfig();
    for (int i=0; i<120; i++) {
        System.out.println("Counter = " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    closeZmq();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

@Override
protected void requestInit() {
    zmqClient.send(getInitMessage().getBytes(),0);
    byte[] reply = zmqClient.recv(0);
    System.out.println("Config - " + (new String(reply)));
}

}
```

Abstract generic service class.

```
public abstract class GenericService {

protected Context zmqContext;
protected Socket zmqClient;
protected int port;
protected int servicePort;
protected String serviceId;

protected static final String addressNoPort = "tcp://127.0.0.1:";

public GenericService() {}

protected void initZmq() {
    zmqContext = ZMQ.context(0);
    zmqClient = zmqContext.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    zmqClient.connect(getAddress());
}

protected void closeZmq() {
    zmqClient.close();
    zmqContext.term();
}

protected abstract void requestInit();

public String getAddress() {
    return addressNoPort+servicePort;
}

public String getInitMessage() {
    return serviceId+":init";
}

}
```

how i run my application.

```
public class TestServiceRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String string : args) {
        System.out.println("Params = "+string);
    }

    System.out.println("Starting Test service ...");

    TestService testService = new TestService(args);
    testService.run();
}

}
```

And my stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.zeromq.ZMQException: No thread available(0x9523dfe)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.connect(Native Method)
    at GenericService.initZmq(GenericService.java:22)
    at TestService.run(TestService.java:25)
    at TestServiceRunner.main(TestServiceRunner.java:13)
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured this one out!

`zmqContext = ZMQ.context(0);` line in GenericService was the problem... The line should have been `zmqContext = ZMQ.context(1);`